# Add Field Attribute to SharepointList (Library)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I get list Metadata for different SharepointLists from calling the Lists-Webservice:

```
        [DocTemplateUrl] => 
        [DefaultViewUrl] => 
        [MobileDefaultViewUrl] => 
        [ID] => {D33D2DEF-1404-4007-8D79-EE9EF75E5AC4}
        [Title] => appdata
        [Description] => 
        [ImageUrl] => /_layouts/15/images/itgen.png?rev=23
        [Name] => {D33D2DEF-1404-4007-8D79-EE9EF75E5AC4}
        [BaseType] => 0
        [FeatureId] => 
        [ServerTemplate] => 125
        [Created] => 20141006 14:46:58
        [Modified] => 20141006 14:46:58
        [LastDeleted] => 20141006 14:46:58
        [Version] => 0
        [Direction] => none
        [ThumbnailSize] => 
        [WebImageWidth] => 
        [WebImageHeight] => 
        [Flags] => 20756
        [ItemCount] => 0
        [AnonymousPermMask] => 0
        [RootFolder] => 
        [ReadSecurity] => 1
        [WriteSecurity] => 1
        [Author] => 3
        [EventSinkAssembly] => 
        [EventSinkClass] => 
        [EventSinkData] => 
        [EmailAlias] => 
        [WebFullUrl] => /
        [WebId] => 1f8e1fa6-d3fa-4393-98f5-deb4b3c89040
        [SendToLocation] => 
        [ScopeId] => 5c1f32b6-cb59-4ac8-b5ba-4eac5788c671
        [MajorVersionLimit] => 0
        [MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit] => 0
        [WorkFlowId] => 
        [HasUniqueScopes] => False
        [NoThrottleListOperations] => False
        [HasRelatedLists] => 
        [Followable] => False
        [AllowDeletion] => False
        [AllowMultiResponses] => False
        [EnableAttachments] => True
        [EnableModeration] => False
        [EnableVersioning] => False
        [HasExternalDataSource] => False
        [Hidden] => True
        [MultipleDataList] => False
        [Ordered] => False
        [ShowUser] => True
        [EnablePeopleSelector] => False
        [EnableResourceSelector] => False
        [EnableMinorVersion] => False
        [RequireCheckout] => False
        [ThrottleListOperations] => False
        [ExcludeFromOfflineClient] => False
        [CanOpenFileAsync] => True
        [EnableFolderCreation] => True
        [IrmEnabled] => False
        [IsApplicationList] => False
        [PreserveEmptyValues] => False
        [StrictTypeCoercion] => False
        [EnforceDataValidation] => False
        [MaxItemsPerThrottledOperation] => 5000
```

Is it possible to add a new field to a list in Sharepoint? I don't want to add a column for the document attributes in a list, but add a field as a list metadata to retrieve it with the lists-webservice.

THX!

Answer (score 0):

You can add existing site column, create a new site column, create a new list column and so on. Just pick your preference, in any normal case your would like to create a site column.

This can be done either by code, powershell or the SharePoint gui

- PowerShell, http://adicodes.com/add-fields-to-list-with-powershell-in-sharepoint-2010/
- Gui, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvPDZ598Xxk
- Code, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms437580(v=office.15).aspx

But since you are asking this I suggest you keep to the GUI until you learn a bit more on SharePoint